# How to use Laravel events?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to be notified when a new user signs up. In my controller I fire an event as follows.

```
Event::fire('myapp.new_user', array($this->data['user']->email));
```

Where do I define the `listener`?

```
Event::listen('myapp.new_user', function ($uid) {
    Message::to("myemail@example.com")
                ->from("myemail@example.com", "My App")
                ->subject('New User')
                ->body("new user")
                ->html(true)
                ->send();
});
```

How does the `listener` know an event fired?

Comment: Laravel on Stackexchange http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel?referrer=VUgOWgZpXyO753uZWv1VMg2

Comment: The proposal was removed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to make sure your listeners are defined prior to your application logic executing, when events are thrown they can only be caught by already registered listeners, it does not look for new ones.

On small projects I just place my listeners in `application/start.php` at the bottom of the file. This file happens before your routes are ran and it serves as sort of a application config file with some logic to it. You need to place these events towards the bottom of the file, at least after the Autoloader mappings have been registered.

On Larger projects I will create `application/listeners.php` and require this file inside `application/start.php` for better readability.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah makes sense. I had created a new library file inside `library/listeners.php` but it didn't occur to me to require it inside  `application/start.php`.

Comment: Thanks. This should be really in the documentation.

Comment: Laravel on Stackexchange http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel?referrer=VUgOWgZpXyO753uZWv1VMg2

Comment: Can we register events at runtime using : Registering A Service Provider At Run-Time

Comment: @owaishanif786 Yes, you can register events at runtime. You can do so with a closure in a service provider like normal, or you can use class based event listeners, see http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events#using-classes-as-listeners which lets you then pass in variables to the Event::listen function containing the class information to register. Do note however, the listener will only be fired for events that occur *after* the event listener is registered.

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
Event::listen('myapp.new_user', function ($uid) {
Message::to("myemail@example.com")
            ->from("myemail@example.com", "My App")
            ->subject('New User')
            ->body("new user")
            ->html(true)
            ->send();
return 'test my event';
});
```

http://laravel.com/docs/events

Answer (score 2):

You can also define classes to handle specific events and then use a Service Provider to register them.

Below is a basic example:

**app/NewUserListener.php**

The listener which is called when the event is fired:

```
class NewUserListener
{
    public function handle($uid)
    {
        // Send an email here
    }
}
```

**app/ListenerServiceProvider.php**

The ServiceProvider - remember and add this to the list of Service Providers in L4 Config.

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ListenerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
        public function register()
        {
            Event::listen('myapp.new_user', 'NewUserListener');
            // Register more events here...
        }
}
```

If you organize listeners etc. into appropriately named folders, it ends up being a lot easier to maintain should you have a bunch of listeners later. You can also instantiate and test the listeners if you write them in this manner.